# Vi: Substitution pattern SQL file. Issue with the Regex

Tags: regex, vi, substitution

I have to modify a SQL file with vi to delete columns that we do not use. As we have a lot of data, I use the search and replace option with a Regex Pattern.

For instance we have :

```
        (1,2956,2026442,4,NULL,NULL,'ZAC DU BOIS DES COMMUNES','',NULL,NULL,'Rue DU LUXEMBOURG',NULL,
    '9999','EVREUX',NULL,1,'27229',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,' Rue DU LUXEMBOURG, 9999 EVREUX',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'2020-07-08 16:34:40',NULL,NULL)
```

So we have 40 columns and I keep 13 ones. My regex is :

```
    (1),2,(3),4-5,(6-14),15-22,(23),24-39,(40)
:%s/(\(.\{-}\),.\{-},\(.\{-}\),.\{-},.\{-},\(.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-}\),.\{-},
    .\{-}, .\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},\(.\{-}\),.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},
    .\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},.\{-},\(.\{-}\))/(\1,\2,\3,\4,\5)/g
```

I enclose in my parenthesis the parts that interest me by putting them in parenthesis (I only get the values in parenthesis on the line above my regex ). Then with the replace I recover these groups.

So normally my result is suppose to be :

```
(1,2026442,NULL,'ZAC DU BOIS DES COMMUNES','',NULL,NULL,'Rue DU LUXEMBOURG',NULL,
        '9999','EVREUX',' Rue DU LUXEMBOURG, 9999 EVREUX',NULL)
```

But Because in `' Rue DU LUXEMBOURG, 9999 EVREUX'` there is a comma (,). My result become :
`(1,2026442,NULL,'ZAC DU BOIS DES COMMUNES','',NULL,NULL,'Rue DU LUXEMBOURG',NULL,'9999','EVREUX',' Rue DU LUXEMBOURG',NULL,NULL)`

Does Someone who is good in Regex can help me ? thanks in advance. If I wasn't clear tell me too, i will try to explain better next time.

Comment: What is the rule here? How can you describe the context where the comma should be "skipped"? Can other fields contain "wild" commas?

Comment: in that particular case, we need that the comma stay because it belong to a column varchar. Actually, the wild comma appear only on string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest matching fields that can be strings with a `%('[^']*'|\w*)` pattern, that is, a non-capturing group that finds either `'` + zero or more non-`'`s and then a `'` char, or any zero or more alphanumeric characters.

Also, the use of non-capturing groups (in Vim, it is `%(...)` in `very magic` mode, or `\%(...\)` in a regular mode) and `very magic` mode can help shorten the pattern.

The whole pattern will look like

```
:%s/\v\(([^,]*),[^,]*,([^,]*),[^,]*,[^,]*,(%('[^']*'|\w*)%(,%('[^']*'|\w*)){8})%(,%('[^']*'|\w*)){8},('[^']*'|\w*)%(,%('[^']*'|\w*)){16},([^,]*)\)/(\1,\2,\3,\4,\5)/g
```

See the [regex demo converted to a PCRE regex](https://regex101.com/r/TQEjzd/1).

Note some fields that are not strings are matched with `[^,]*` that matches zero or more chars other than a comma. The `%(,%('[^']*'|\w*)){8}` like patterns match (here) 8 occurrences of a sequence of a `,` char + `'...'` substring or zero or more word chars.